# Functional equations and Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that 
$g(x)+g(y)=g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$
has the unique continuous solution that is $g(x)=cx^2$ for a constant $c$.

I can either plug the function in and see that it is a solution, however I'm having problem proving it's uniqueness. I was also given the hint that I can somehow relate this to the Cauchy functional equation and use the known result, but again I'm not sure how to do that.

Edit: 
Let $f(x^2)=g(x)$

we have(or not?)

$f(x^2)+f(y^2)=g(x)+g(y)=g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=f(x^2+y^2)$

and this being for $x\ge0$.

Is this not the cauchy functional equation for non negative x?

Comment: Now I see what you mean. The functional equation $f(x^2) + f(y^2) = f(x^2 + y^2)$ is almost the form of Cauchy's, but it's not there yet. From here you can write, for $x, y \ge 0$, $$f(x) + f(y) = f((\sqrt{x})^2) + f((\sqrt{y})^2) = f((\sqrt{x})^2 + (\sqrt{y})^2) = f(x + y)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $g$ is continuous and satisfies the above functional equation. Setting $x = y = 0$, we deduce $g(0) = 0$. Then setting $y = 0$, we obtain $g(x) + g(0) = g(\sqrt{x^2})$, i.e., $g(x) = g(|x|)$. So we may restrict $g$ to $[0,\infty)$. Doing so, we may replace $x$ by $\sqrt{x}$ and $y$ by $\sqrt{y}$ in the functional equation to get $g(\sqrt{x}) + g(\sqrt{y}) = g(\sqrt{x + y})$. Let $f(x) = g(\sqrt{x})$, for $x \ge 0$. Then $f$ is continuous and satisfies Cauchy's functional equation $f(x) + f(y) = f(x + y)$. Hence, $f(x) = cx$ for some constant $c$. Thus $g(x) = f(x^2) = cx^2$ for all nonnegative $x$. Now since $g(x) = g(|x|)$ for all $x$, we conclude that $g(x) = cx^2$ for all $x$.

Comment: I'm curious, would it be the same if I take $f(x^2)=g(x)$ rather than $f(x)=g(\sqrt{x})$ to begin with?

Comment: The two equations $f(x^2) = g(x)$ and $f(x) = g(\sqrt{x})$ are equivalent for $x \ge 0$. However, the equation $f(x^2) = g(x)$ is not useful in obtaining Cauchy's functional equation, since $g$ does not necessarily satisfy that equation.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. I'm not sure that I can see it for myself; when would g not satisfy that equation?

Comment: The point of introducing $f$ is that $f$ satisfies Cauchy's equation (even if $g$ doesn't). To see that $g$ may not satisfy Cauchy's equation, suppose $g(x) = x^2$. Then $g(x) + g(y) = g(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ for all $x$ and $y$, but $g(x + y) \neq g(x) + g(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$: $$g(1 + 2) = (1 + 2)^2 = 9 \neq 1 + 4 = g(1) + g(2)$$

Comment: I've edited my main post with what I meant. g doesn't seem to have to satisfy Cauchy either using $f(x^2)$.